# How to port django 1.11 to django 2.2 and python 2.7 to 3.5?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, porting

I need main points which could crash my code when porting a project that is in Django 1.11 with python 2.75  to Django 2.2 with python 3.5 .If someone can point me to the links or give a detailed summary about things i should make sure to correct while porting the code .

I have read this guide for porting python2 to python3 .https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-port-python-2-code-to-python-3.Anything else will be highly appreciated .

Comment: First port to Python 3, it is a far more substantial change than the Django version. In the 10 years since Python 3 was released hundreds of guides about porting it have been published, a Stack Overflow answer can't really add anything useful.